# iPhone - Call method on another class using self.class

Tags: objective-c, methods

New to Obj-c.

In my "Owner" class I am calling a method to feed the bird, but I get an error "No Visible @interface for "NSObject" declares the selector eat" on the line:

```
[self.pet eat];
```

Main.m

```
Owner * joe = [[Owner alloc] init];
Bird * joePet = [[Bird alloc] init];
joe.pet = joePet;
```

Owner.h

```
#import "Bird.h"

@interface Owner : NSObject 
{

int populationCount;
}

@property NSString *name;
@property NSObject *pet;

-(void)makePetMakeNoise;
-(void)feedPet;

@end
```

Owner.m

```
#import "Owner.h"
#import "Bird.h"

-(void)feedPet
{
[self.pet eat];

}
```

Bird.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Bird : NSObject
{
NSString *name;
NSString *noise;
BOOL canMakeNoise;
} 

-(void)makeNoise:(int)howManyTimes;
-(void)eat;

@end
```

Bird.m

```
#import "Bird.h"
-(void)eat
{
NSLog(@"%@ is eating...", name);
}
```

All I want to do is call that eat function from Owner.m, how can I do this?

Comment: Is -(void)eat declared in Bird.h File?

Comment: yes. -(void)eat; is before the @ end but not within the @interface {} brackets. is this right?

Comment: can you post some more code on Owner and Bird class?

Comment: Did you include `Bird.h` in `Owner.m`?

Comment: Also, does the error message actually say "makeNosie" (with "Noise" mis-spelled) or is that just a transcription error between the compiler and here?

Comment: I updated the code to show what I'm including, and i actually meant the "eat" class, not the makeNoise class.

Comment: Would help to see the interface definition for `Owner` as well.

Comment: Okay, I think that all the code is up now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it's not an error, it's only a warning. Your app will execute just fine, but the compiler is warning you that you *might* have made a mistake.

The warning will go away if you change this line:

```
@property NSObject *pet;
```

To this:

```
@property Bird *pet;
```

Typically you would define a class `Animal`, with `Bird` as a subclass of that. The `-eat` method would be in the animal class and also in the bird class. Then you can do:

```
@property Animal *pet;
```

Comment: Perfect! To clarify, it definitely is an error in my xCode. It says build failed if I leave it as NSObject. Thank you, it works perfectly changing it to Bird!

Comment: Maybe there is some code elsewhere that relies on it being declared as `Bird`. The highlighted line of code `[self.pet eat]` should only show a warning.